# How to get conversation with single phone number on Android

Tags: android, database, sms

I have problem with that. If i use query where adress = number, app doesn't show any data(maybe, it's because that number could be in different formats at DB, like xxx or +xxx). Is there any simple way to get conversation?

Here is my code

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),null,"address = " + number,null,null);
        Log.wtf("", cursor.toString());
        SMS sms;
        cursor.moveToLast();
        do{
            sms = new SMS();
            if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"))==2) sms.isMe = true;
            else                                                sms.isMe = false;
            try{
                sms.text = encryptor.decrypt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));
            }catch (Exception e){sms.text=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));}
            sms.date = convertMilis(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
            list.add(sms);
        }while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
```

Phone number i get from edittext with PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you make it clearer by adding what you are trying to accomplish and/or relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @iRuth, i had added my code